# Notepad row count inconsistent before and after enabling *and then* un-enabling word wrap

Tags: csv, notepad, numbering, word-wrap

I have a CSV file that contains 10,001 rows *(10,000 rows of data and one row for the headers)*.

When opening it in Notepad, scrolling to the very bottom, and clicking on the last row, I get "3659" rows:

[Image of notepad before enabling word wrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csIo8.png)

But after enabling word wrap, I get:

[Image of notepad after enabling word wrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MLGn.png)

Finally, un-enabling word wrap will keep the row count as the accurate "10,001":

[Image of notepad after enabling and un-enabling word wrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPg1g.png)

Why was it "3659" before enabling and un-enabling word wrap?

Comment: What method do you use to go to the bottom?

Comment: @harrymc Regular scrolling by clicking on the scrollbar and dragging,

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Would it be possible to post the file online?

Comment: @harrymc Here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/datafiniti/fast-food-restaurants

Comment: This download requires login.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad is not a great tool for this job (my view).

It most likely combined CSV lines because of the lack of line wrap. So then line count at this point is lower than the total number of lines.

Then wrapping got the number of lines correct.

Now then at this point, I am not certain but in the last step, it may still be internally wrapping the lines, wich in turn, keeps the line count correct.

As noted, this (Notepad) is not the best tool for CSV files.

Comment: The file is this one: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/datafiniti/fast-food-restaurants

Comment: The link is to a food and restaurant site!

Comment: No... it's Kaggle... an online community of data scientists and machine learning practitioners, where we can find all sorts of csv datasets...

Comment: I did not see that.